# OpenCart mp3 preview

Tags: php, audio, opencart

What is the best method and player for giving an audio preview on an OpenCart store. This would involve uploading the full track and then extracting a portion to be played

Answer (score 1):

[m3psplt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net) is by far your best bet.

It can sometimes be a little dicey to install (particularly on CentOS, other RH based distros) but it's really the only solution I've found.

I usually run a script that analyzes the mp3 with [getid3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) to get the length, then I calculate the halfway point of the mp3, and pass that plus thirty seconds to mp3splt via the exec command to mp3splt.

It works great when you can get it to install properly. If you're on debian/ubuntu it's actually a cinch to install via aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I could think do do would be to wrap your command line unix audio editing utilities in a php script to basically create a "grab 2 minute head of MP3" function, then run that on files when they are uploaded. then yes, save them in a "previews" area of the file system and store the filename in a DB table for later reference.

Comment: what unix audio editing utilities are we talking about here? cuz i am not too familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a PHP script that could fit your needs (please note I didn't tested it). You can find it [here](http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class). The class interface seems simple and functional. Anyway, you will need to modify your OpenCart product template to expose the preview command.

Comment: The link you provide is dead. Link only answers aren't good, for things like this. You should have told the name of the script.